# How was the three-breast effect done for the prostitute?

Tags: effects, make-up, total-recall-2012, total-recall

In the first Total Recall movie, the main cast visits a bar, and one of the patrons was a woman that had three breasts (instead of the usual two for non-injured adult human women).  Did the actress ([Lycia Naff](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0619031/)) wear a plate with all three visible breasts?  Or was only one prosthetic breast made and the character's two outer breasts were the ones the actress brought herself?

(A quick search found an announcement from the actress, [Kaitlyn Leeb](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm3037446/), playing the equivalent character from the remake saying that a plate was used for her; none of the on-screen breasts of the character came from the actress.)

Comment: It should be very easy with prosthetics.

Comment: It's only her breasts you can see. The glands are the structures inside.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### It was a large chest plate

[An interview with Lycia Naff](https://www.theatlantic.com/entertainment/archive/2012/08/finally-truth-about-three-breasted-total-recall-character/325086/) describes the process:

> All three mammary glands are fake. **In fact, the prosthetic is a large chest plate that starts at the neck and goes down to my belly button. This huge piece is applied using spirit gum on the very thin ends of this porous, spongy piece.** It took between five and eight hours to apply. Needless to say my call times were 3:30 am! They'd lay me down in a dentist-style chair that reclines back. And two makeup artists would have at me while I napped. The makeup room was very private. No one but me, my three boobs and the artists at hand.

Answer (score 6):

There is an interview with [Lycia Naff](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0619031/), the actor that played Mary (*"the triple-breasted hooker from Mars!"*¹) where the subtext does indicate that it was a full prosthetic.

> ...
> But still, I felt really exposed. It didn’t hit me until the first moment where the scene called for me to expose myself, because what came over me was such shame. Which was weird, **because they weren’t my breasts**, and it was what I had signed up to do. So why was I getting a reality shock now?
> ...
>   
> <sub>*source:* [A Candid Conversation With Total Recall’s Original Three-Breasted Woman](https://www.vulture.com/2012/08/total-recall-three-breasted-woman-interview.html)</sub>

---

¹ <sub>This is a direct quote from the interview in Ms. Naff's own words and is not taken frivolously out of context.</sub>